# How to fetch data from tables where there is one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created three tables like Product, Brands and ProductBrands in ms sql server
These tables contains data as the following

Products (PId - PName)

- 1 - Mobiles
- 2 - T.V
- 3 - A.C

Brands (BId - BName)

- 1 - Samsung
- 2 - Sony
- 3 - L.G

ProductsBrands (PBId - PId - BId)

- 1 - 1 - 1
- 2 - 1 - 2
- 3 - 1 - 3
- 4 - 2 - 1
- 5 - 2 - 3

...

...

Now I have to fetch from tables the following feilds

- Product Id
- PName
- BId
- BName

Basically I have to fetch all the Brands assigned to a Products

Please help me!!! I am very new to this

Comment: Just an FYI, this pattern is called 'many to many'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  P.PId ,
        P.PName,
        B.BId,
        B.BName
FROM    Products P
JOIN    ProductsBrands  PB On PB.PId  = P.PId 
JOIN    Brands  B ON B.BId  = PB.BId
```

See, whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Based on your answer I have created a Fiddle example for the user to understand - PLEASE CHECK - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe6e1/3

Comment: If I have PDescription in the Product Table so I will write P.PDescription after P.PName, in the above code. Is it correct way to display PName and PDescription twice or more as there is one to many relationship... I am just asking... please reply

Comment: PDesscription is related through PId, so there wont be any issues at all.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct:(Fetch all brands assigned to a Product)

```
select BName from Brands where BId in 
(select distinct Bid from ProductsBrands where PId = (select PId from Products where PName = @input))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... let me try it

Answer (score 2):

First you probably don't need "PBid" field for "ProductBrand" table instead you can use composite primary key as the primary key "*PId,BId*".

here is the SQL code.

```
Select PId, PName, BId, BName
from product p , brand b , productbrands pd
where p.pid = pd.pid and b.bid = pd.bid
```

Remember if your one product belong to one and only one brand then you  can reduce it to only 2 tables

ex -product(pid , pname,bid) and 
    brand(bid , bname)